# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sessions"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, rubygems

I recently just migrated my app from sqlite3 to postgresql so I can push to heroku, I'm using Rails 5.0.3. But every time I try to run this code:

```
    taps pull postgres://rubijoan@localhost/inventory_development
    http://rubijoan:yoloholo@localhost:3000
```

I get "Unable to fetch tables information from" error and then when I check my server I can't get the db because I get a routing error

```
    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sessions"):
```

I've been stuck for ages, I'm self learning Ruby so some explanation would be helpful please. Here are some photos that might help.

When I run rails route:
[My rails route photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFmpd.png)

and

My routes.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/show'

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :comments
  resources :users
  root to: redirect('/ideas')
  resources :ideas do
    resources :reactions, only: :create

  end
end
```

My controller is with the default I got with the devise gem but I added 
registrations as I added new fields to when a user signs up

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    private

end
```

Comment: In my projects i have. devise_for :users, :path => '', :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations'} try with that or just add this to your routes:    post "sessions"  :and check if there is a new error

Comment: @ErickEduardoGarcia  thank you for answering! I tried to implement what you said but when I did add this code in my routes.rb devise_for :users, :path => '', :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations'} it didn't work but when I added post 'sessions' it gave me an error 'ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant SessionsController):'

Comment: You have to create a sessions_controller.rb  just like the registrations_controller but with "< Devise::SessionsController"

Comment: @ErickEduardoGarcia Oh sorry! That worked but I get this error now: `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'sessions' could not be found for SessionsController):`

Comment: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/sessions"):

This suggestions something is trying to POST to /sessions, are you using all the appropriate prefixes in your code?

Comment: You have to create the sessions action inside the controller. def sessions end; but you are going to mess with other things. If you have a github link of your code paste it and i will fixit for you

Comment: @ErickEduardoGarcia Some explanation would be so super cool please https://github.com/geeitsjo/LocaGrid